# Buscar por número em tabela MySQL com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um form de busca onde o usuário digita um número e se ele for igual ao número que está no banco de dados ele retorna os dados desse número.
Mas, quando clico no `button enviar` ele me mostra a pagina `teste.php` com o seguinte erro (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '232' at line 1) segue o codigo.

Banco de dados:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_numeros` (
  `numero` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `funcionario` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `rca` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `regiao` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `nchip` int(120) NOT NULL,
  `imei` int(120) NOT NULL
) PRIMARY KEY (`numero`);
```

Form:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="post" action="teste.php" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="numerodigitado" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar Número">
    </div>
        <button type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

teste.php:

```
<?php
include_once("../conn/conexao.php");//faz a conexao com o banco de dados

    if(isset($_POST['numerodigitado'])){
        $palavra = trim($_POST['numerodigitado']);
    }else{
        $palavra = trim($_GET['numerodigitado']);
    }

    if($palavra != NULL){
        // Retorna apenas os registros PARECIDOS com 'palavra', limitando à 10 registros por página
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_numeros WHERE numero LIKE '%$palavra%' ";
    }else{
        // Retorna todos os registros do BD
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_numeros ORDER BY numero ";
    }

    $comparar = mysqli_query($conexao, $palavra) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
    if($comparar):
    echo "<script>
            alert('Número encontrado.');

        </script>"; 
    else:
        echo "<script>
                alert('Ocorreu um erro ao mostrar o número.');

            </script>";
    endif;

?>
```

Comment: Mas seu arquivo PHP faz nada, mesmo. A única coisa que você faz é definir o valor de `$palavra` e de `$sql`, mas você nunca executa a consulta no banco e não exibe nenhum resultado na tela. Não faltou aí um `mysqli_query` para executar a consulta e iterar sobre os resultados? Se não faz ideia do que eu falei, talvez seja interessante você reler a [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: $comparar = mysqli_query($conexao, $palavra) or die (mysqli_error($conexao)); criei esse campo e um if para o $comparar porém ele está aparecendo um seguinte erro: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '232' at line 1

Comment: Então edite a pergunta, coloque o código completo e a mensagem de erro. Essas são informações essenciais para verificar o problema e não devem ser omitidas.

Comment: editei lá amigo

Comment: $comparar = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) e não $palavra. O erro é esse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lembrando que abaixo usarei uma variável de conexão, denominada $conn, troque pela sua variável criada para realizar a conexão no banco de dados

```
<?php

  include_once("../conn/conexao.php");//faz a conexao com o banco de dados

  if(isset($_POST['numerodigitado'])){

    $numerodigitado = $_POST['numerodigitado'];

    $result = "SELECT * FROM tb_numeros WHERE numero = '$numerodigitado' ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

    if($resultado -> num_rows > 0){
       echo " .$row['campo1']. ";
       echo " .$row['campo2']. ";
       echo " .$row['campo3']. ";
    } else {
       echo "<script>alert('Ocorreu um erro ao buscar o número');</script>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Estou tentando ajudar, mas estou no serviço e muito corrido, estão me interrompendo demais ai acabei misturando o código creio. poderia editar a resposta ?

Comment: ele imprimiu isso : SELECT * FROM tb_numeros WHERE numero LIKE '%232%'

Comment: continua sem mostrar nada, eu quero que se o numero digitado for igual ao que esta cadastrado no banco ele mostre os dados que estão cadastrados nesse numero... até agora só mostra uma pagina em branco...

Comment: @Ferb verifique agora com este código, e lembre-se dentro de onde está campo1, campo2, campo3 coloque os campos referentes ao banco de dados

Comment: valeu, deu certo isso mesmo